# Literating list by for loop gives whole list instead of each element in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

the script needs two input arguments from sys.argv

```
$ python3 check_process.py mem_info.json "['192.168.24.9', '192.168.24.13', '192.168.24.22', '192.168.24.38']"
```

then those argv will pass to the parameter

nodes

```
nodes = sys.argv[2:]
```

I'm trying to iterate over each elements of nodes

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    passed_args = len(sys.argv)
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    nodes = sys.argv[2:]

    for i in nodes:
        print("node:" + " " + i)
```

but it gives me the whole list

```
node: ['192.168.24.9', '192.168.24.13', '192.168.24.22', '192.168.24.38']
```

the thing I wanted is

```
node: '192.168.24.9'
node: '192.168.24.13'
node: '192.168.24.22'
node: '192.168.24.38'
```

Is there something to do with argv ? I've tried many ways but it doesn't help

Comment: Just put your IP addresses on the command line, separated by spaces: `python3 check_process.py mem_info.json 192.168.24.9 192.168.24.13 192.168.24.22`

Comment: @ThierryLathuille actually those ips will automatically pass from other script and I cannot change its passed arguments. :(

Comment: This would be an important point to explain at the start of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sys.argv` is a list of strings.  The fact that you're passing a string that "looks like" a list is immaterial.  The second element of argv is a single string containing the text `['192.168.24.9', '192.168.24.13', '192.168.24.22', '192.168.24.38']`.  You would need to parse that into a list.

The simpler solution, I think, is to pass the addresses on the command line as separate parameters:

```
$ python3 check_process.py mem_info.json 192.168.24.9 192.168.24.13 192.168.24.22 192.168.24.38
```

This way, each IP address will be a separate element of `argv`, and `argv[2:]` will return the list of nodes that you want.

If you can't do that, you need to start with `argv[2]` as a single string and parse it into a list.  Use the `strip` method to remove the square brackets, and use the `split` method to create the list.